# Mapbox vector tiles version 2 MVTv2 and Geoserver 2.13.x

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I use WMS on Geoserver to display MVTs in conjunction with mapboxgl.js v0.45.0.
A OSM road layer renders 1:1 on top of the Mapbox base layer, so far so good.

However, I got a warning from the js console:

`Vector tile source "geoserver" layer "roads" does not use vector tile spec v2 and therefore may have some rendering errors.`

Does anybody know about the protobuf version used in *geoserver*? 
I reviewed the source code of the java tile package used and of the plugin in branch v2.13.x. Seems like MVTv1 is used and triggers the javascript warning. Can someone point me to the right location in the java code? Maybe we can upgrade the MVT package so that MVTv2.1 is used.

---

Here is the source code of the javascript integration in accordance with a GEOS bug report by another user. That works for me.
[see here on GEOS JIRA](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7997?focusedCommentId=69052&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-69052)

Comment: I'd love to know about this as well. If you find out anything, I'd be grateful if you'll keep us posted here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using no.ecc.vectortile's java-vector-tile.

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/extension/vectortiles/pom.xml#L31-L34

We use a subclass of the main encoder - we do our own clipping so no need to do it twice.

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/extension/vectortiles/src/main/java/no/ecc/vectortile/VectorTileEncoderNoClip.java

The entire VT plugin is here;
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src/extension/vectortiles

Another ticket with some info is here;
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7920

There are other java VT libraries, and I think some of them do v2.  I'm not sure if a newer version of java-vector-tile does that or not.

Best place to ask questions about geoserver is on the geoserver-devel mailing list.